# Calculating Standard Deviation of Array Recursively

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, standard-deviation

My assignment is to use recursion to calculate the standard deviation of an Arraylist. I understand how to calculate standard deviation as I have done it without recursion I just need help implementing recursion. I would like to use a helper function if possible.

**This is the recursive method and helper method i use to calculate the average:**

```
public static double calcAvg( ArrayList <Integer> list ) {
    double sum = calcSum(list, 0);
    return sum / list.size();
}

private static int calcSum( ArrayList <Integer> list, int i ) {
    if( i < list.size() ){
        return list.get(i) + calcSum(list, i + 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**This is my Standard Deviation method that needs recursion:**

```
public static double calcStd (ArrayList <Integer> list){
    int sum = 0;
    double average = calcAvg(list);

    for ( int i : list){
        sum += Math.pow((i - average), 2);
    }
    return Math.sqrt( sum / ( list.size() - 1 ));
}
```

**Attempt:**

```
public static double calcStd( ArrayList <Integer> list){
    double avg = calcAvg(list);
    double sum = sumSquareDiffs(list, avg, 0);
    return Math.sqrt( sum / ( list.size() - 1 ));
}
private static double sumSquareDiffs(ArrayList <Integer> list, double avg, int i){
    if (i < list.size()){
        return Math.pow((list.get(i) - avg), 2) + sumSquareDiffs(list, avg, i + 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking us boldly to do your homeworks?!?

Comment: @cmbarbu No, i am simply asking for steps in the right direction to modify the code i have already written to use recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the recursive definition of `calcSum`, and see how you can make your `calcStd` recursive as well. You need to make another "helper" method for this - `sumSquareDiffs`. The signature of the method would look like this:

```
double sumSquareDiffs(ArrayList <Integer> list, double avg, int i) {
    ...
}
```

To implement the method, see what `calcSum` does, and do the same thing, except instead of adding `list.get(i)` you need to add

```
Math.pow((list.get(i) - avg), 2)
```

With this method in hand, you would be able to make `calcStd` rely on only recursive methods.

Comment: You should probably mention to take the sqrt of the final answer. [sauce](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation-formulas.html)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight This was just what i needed to lead me in the right direction. I have added my attempt in my post but I am getting the incorrect calculation. Any ideas on where I made a mistake?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight missed that. my bad. Good job.